# Converting \r\n in a mailto link

Tags: php, mysqli, mailto

I've tried every combination and read every post I can find but I still cannot make this work.

I have comments that are kept in a MySQL DB. I create a simple mailto link but if the user has entered carriage returns into the textarea it displays like this:

> Comments: Good\r\nMore good

I'm trying to convert the \r\n to %0D%0A but I've been totally incapable of getting it to replace these special characters.

Comment: And why you want this and from wher you got tis stuff? show us some code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to resolve it with the use of single not double quotes:

```
$edit = str_replace('\r\n', '%0D%0A', $edit);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it in mysql, you can do it like this:

```
UPDATE xxxxxx set comments = replace(comments,'\r\n','');
```

IF you want to do it in PHP, you can do something like this:

```
$edit = str_replace("\n", '', $edit); 
$edit = str_replace("\r", '', $edit);
```

Comment: That will strip the codes out of the string. He wants to replace them with ascii 10 & ascii 13.